# Change size of geom_point based on values in column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have plotted data with `geom_point` and the size of the data point is set by the the values in a column. I want to increase the overall size of these points ( and also keeping the relative sizes). I have tried to just multiply all the values with a number, but the point sizes stay the same. How can I increase the overall point size?
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify the `range` in `scale_size()` or if you prefer `scale_radius()`

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = hp)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = mpg), alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_size(range = c(5, 10))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>